# How to intercept a request on time basis in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have a request that will be called every 5 seconds,  I can use intercept to capture it and count how many times it has been called, but is there a way  I can tell how often it has been called?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you have in the intercept. If you use a routeHandler function, it's easy to record the call time in an array

```js
const calls = []
calls.push(Date.now())  // start

intercept(url, (req) => {
  calls.push(Date.now())  // each call
})
```